# For loop within the function to generate frequency of classes for barchart?

Tags: python, function, class, bar-chart

```
class Visualizer:
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.df = dataframe
       
    def plot_bar(self, x,height, width, title = "  ",xlabel = "  ", ylabel = "  ",color = "   ", **kwargs):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
        
        if type(x) == type("xyz"):
            x = self.df[x].value_counts().index
       
            
        plt.bar(x= x,
                height= height,
                width = width,
                color= color,
                alpha=0.5)

        plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = 20)
        plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize = 20)
        plt.xticks(fontsize = 16)
        plt.yticks(fontsize = 16)
    
        leg = plt.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True)
        leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
        plt.title(title, fontsize = 20)
        plt.show()
```

I call this function as below:

```
vizu =visualization("df")
vizu.plot_bar("State",200, 0.25, " Area vs State", "Area","Rentalprice",'r' )
```

How to have a loop which generates the frequency of classes in a column(state) within the function?
Also, I am attaching the screen shot of the output as the reference.

[image]

**This is my 1st stack flow question. Any mistake, please accept my apologizes!**

Comment: Are you looking for [Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)?

Comment: Yes. It is for series.values_counts. Thank you.